# How to convert python tf.Tensor into C++ Tensor using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, swig, pybind11

I am developing a Python library in C++ using pybind11. This library is meant to be used with deep learning packages like TensorFlow, so some of the functions it exposes take TensorFlow objects as argument, and in particular `tf.Tensor` instances. At C++ level, these functions are defined with the following prototype:

```
void f(const py11::object& theTensor) {
   ...
}
```

I'm looking for a way to get the C++ `tensorflow::Tensor` wrapped by the `py11::object` that is being passed.

My understanding of TensorFlow is that it uses SWIG to create the Python wrapper to the C++ interface. However, I couldn't find where the `tf.Tensor` wrapper is defined, and I'm not familiar with the way SWIG exposes C++ classes as Python classes.

I should be able to retrieve a `PyObject*` pointer from the `py11::object` using `theTensor.ptr()`, but then I don't know how to convert this into a pointer to a C++ Tensor object.

Comment: See the first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637732/how-to-pass-list-of-structs-to-c-in-swig-python]). You can do things like `reinterpret_cast<Tensor*>(SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis(theTensor))`, but as with any use of `reinterpret_cast` you should definitely verify the pointer you're casting is what you think it is

Comment: Actually some more digging made me find that the Tensor python class is defined in framework/ops.py so it's not a C++ class exposed "as is" to Python by SWIG.